# Paging via Number of Result Record vs COUNT(*)

Tags: count, pagination

I have been working on fixing a piece of code for a customer that has been very slow for them.

I have made that fix, and thats all lovely, but I noticed something odd in the paging.

When the query is executed, it does NOT contain a `LIMIT` keyword. Then, based on the per-page value and the current page the viewer is on, the result reader is told to fetch from the index of the Record at `(perPage * currentPage - 1)` to the Record at `(perPage * currentPage) - 1`, and the total number of Records the result has are used to determine the total number of pages.

So, are there any benefits doing it this way as opposed to using the `LIMIT` keyword, and a separate `COUNT(*)` query (possibly only done once per search context)?

Comment: So....MySQL...or....?

Comment: @MarkSinkinson On the system in question, it was Oracle, and although I know that each Database will have its own optimizations, I was wondering about it on a more database agnostic level

Comment: well, either way, I am wondering what the performance comparison would be between using a record count function on the result object (from `select * from ...`) and just using `select count(*) from ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah, fair enough. Link deleted

Comment: @cgoddard Oracle didn't have `LIMIT` before 12c came out (you had to use a subquery and `rownum`), so that probably explains the lack of it :)